# Detect if regedit.exe is open

Tags: vb.net, regedit

I know how to detect windows by title name in VB.NET and it works

```
If p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Registry") Then
```

But the Registry editor has a different name in each language, so how can I detect "regedit.exe" by ProcessName?

I tried it that way, but it doesn't seem to work at all:

```
If p.ProcessName.Contains("regedit") Then

If p.StartInfo.FileName.Contains("regedit") Then
```

So how can I detect it?

Comment: `Process.GetProcesses().Any(Function(p)p.ProcessName.Contains("regedit"))` works just fine for me. Please [edit] the question and provide a [repro].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all `regedit.exe` processes with the method [`GetProcessesByName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("regedit")
```

This returns an array of `Process`.